# Munin Aggregate Graph

Tags: nginx, munin, graph

I am trying to aggregate munin graphs (http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/aggregate_examples)  for my nginx_request plugin (http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/nginx_request/version/2)

The configuration I have is:

```
[lb1.domain.com]
    address 192.168.170.112
    use_node_name yes

[lb2.domain.com]
    address 192.168.174.9
    use_node_name yes

[TRAFFIC;Aggregated]
  update no
  contacts no
  nginx_requests.graph_title nGinx requests
  nginx_requests.graph_vlabel nGinx requests per second
  nginx_requests.draw LINE2
  nginx_requests.graph_args --base 1000
  nginx_requests.graph_category nginx
  nginx_requests.label req/sec
  nginx_requests.type DERIVE
  nginx_requests.min 0
  nginx_requests.graph_order outputrequest
  nginx_requests.outputrequest.sum \
    lb1.domain.com:nginx_request.request \
    lb2.domain.com:nginx_request.request
```

I have also tried a few different configuration settings, but the graphs are not working. Can someone help me finding the correct config settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that finally worked for me

```
[lb;lb1]
    address X.X.X.X
    use_node_name yes

[lb;lb2]
    address Y.Y.Y.Y
    use_node_name yes

[lb;lb3]
    address Z.Z.Z.Z
    use_node_name yes

[lb;Aggregated]
  update no
  contacts no
  nginx_requests.graph_title nGinx requests (Total)
  nginx_requests.graph_vlabel nGinx requests (Total) per second
  nginx_requests.total.draw LINE2
  nginx_requests.graph_args --base 1000
  nginx_requests.graph_category nginx
  nginx_requests.total.label req/sec
  nginx_requests.total.type DERIVE
  nginx_requests.total.min 0
  nginx_requests.total.sum \
    lb1:nginx_request.request \
    lb2:nginx_request.request \
    lb3:nginx_request.request
```